# Getting Netlogon information with an ADSI script

Tags: vbscript, attributes, active-directory, adsi

The following screenshot shows a snippet of network communication as sniffed by Wireshark. It is a part of the login process, where a domain-joined client tries to login to a Windows Server 2008 R2 (which is the domain controller). The protocol used is Connectionless LDAP (CLDAP), also known as LDAP Ping.

[image: Active Directory Communication - Sniffed by Wireshark]

Sample response:

[image]

It seems that the query is trying to get some "filtered" information regarding the "Netlogon" attribute.
This attribute is documented here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223260.aspx

Moreover, as described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223254.aspx, this attribute is operational, meaning that:

> ... the server returns the attribute only when it is explicitly requested.

I tried to write a simple ADSI script to get more info about this attribute, but I got an error. Here's the script:

```
Set obj = GetObject("LDAP://rootDSE")

attArray = Array("netlogon") 
obj.GetInfoEx attArray, 0
WScript.Echo obj.netlogon
```

- Error message: Object doesn't support this property or method: 'obj.netlogon'.
- Error code: 800A01B6

Could you please help me with the script?

Comment: Obviously you did not apply the filter as did the Wireshark comm. Retry with that filter first.

Comment: @Michael-O: Thanks for the comment. I kinda liked to see what other values are kept in the "netlogon" attribute, so I didn't apply any filter. Is that possible? I mean, is it possible to apply a wildcard filter, like "*", to get everything?

Comment: the netlogon attribute cannot be found in RootDSE. Simply perform this search: `(netlogon=*)` and you'll see all leafs with that attribute.

Comment: @Michael-O: Thanks again. I tried to perform the `(netlogon=*)` in several ways, but as I'm new to ADSI scripting, I couldn't get the result. Could you please write your solution as an answer?

Comment: I am not using ADSI but a LDAP browser. I was not able to find any node with that attrbute in our forest. The forest is huge, milliions of objects.

Comment: @Michael-O: Me too. But, according to Microsft documentation cited in the question, as well as Wireshark sniffed traffic, it DOES exist (and is a rootDSE operational attribute).

Comment: Sorry, not here. Any example source what should be in that attribute?

Comment: @Michael-O: I finally understood what's wrong: According to [this page](http://books.google.com/books?id=Tt_-3NRBVdEC&pg=PA195): "The client then uses this IP address to establish a UDP connection to the LDAP service on the DC and query for the NETLOGON attribute in RootDSE. This attribute doesn't actually exist in the directory; rather, it's used to perform an LDAP ping." More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223811(v=prot.20).aspx.

Comment: Are you able to share the response of the server too?

Comment: @Michael-O: I modified the question, to include both the response, and the method used for querying operational attributes (using `GetInfoEx`). Obviously, the new method is for "real" attributes and won't work for "virtual" attributes such as Netlogon. (I just put it there for future reference)

Comment: I guess, this won't work with ADSI because it operates on TCP, does it?

Comment: @Michael-O: I'm not sure. There might be one or more problems: 1) The TCP vs. UDP, as you mentioned. 2) No filters means no answer, or even the error. 3) `Netlogon` is not a real attribute, and therefore cannot be queried ordinarily. Anyway, I got enough information to proceed (in the link regarding LDAP ping). Thanks for collaboration!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For later reference, I provide one of my comments above as the answer:

> I finally understood what's wrong: According to [this page](http://books.google.com/books?id=Tt_-3NRBVdEC&pg=PA195): "The client then uses this IP address to establish a UDP connection to the LDAP service on the DC and query for the NETLOGON attribute in RootDSE. This attribute doesn't actually exist in the directory; rather, it's used to perform an LDAP ping." More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223811(v=prot.20).aspx